# Use of single quotes when running remote ssh

Tags: linux

I have looked at all of the answers regarding questions similar to this but have not found anything useful - how do you use more than one set of single quotes in a remote SSH command when the syntax of both of the commands demands single quotes in order to work correctly?

Such as this:

```
for host in $(<input_list.txt)
 do
  ssh $host 'echo $(hostname -s):$(ls -l /etc/rc.local | awk '{print $1,$6}')'
 done
```

I have tried using "set -x" but the output is all but useless and tried multiple combinations of single and double quotes with no success.  I cannot believe there is no way this can be done.

Comment: Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: The awk doesn't need singlequotes if you add spaces like `'echo $(hostname -s):$(ls -l /etc/rc.local | awk "{print $ 1,$ 6}")'`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 What is the significance of the spaces when using the double quotes after the awk command?

Comment: If the command passed to the remote shell has a double-quoted string containing `$1`, the remote shell treats that as a positional parameter and substitutes it, which you don't want. If instead it contains `$ 1` the shell does _not_ substitute it and passes it to awk just as if it were single-quoted, and awk _does_ recognize it as referring to field 1 of the input record.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
for host in $(<input_list.txt); do
    ssh $host <<'EOF'
echo $(hostname -s):$(ls -l /etc/rc.local | awk '{print $1,$6}')
EOF
done
```

Comment: Great!! It worked however I am curious as to how the single quotes around the EOF forced the system to read the remote hostname instead of the local.

Comment: @JTelep It's part of the syntax for [here documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) that, if any part of `word` (in `<<word`) is quoted, then the content of the here document is treated literally. This is how you tell your shell that you don't want any expansions to be performed on the text in the here document. In this case, writing `EOF` as `'EOF'` prevents text like `$(...)` from triggering [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in the shell reading the here document, which is the local shell.